# The index of my tableview cells changes after search

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

After searching for a cell, I would like to click on it and do an action. But after searching, the index of my cell is always 0 because it is the first thing in the table view.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var SearchBar: UISearchBar!

    var Array = ["One","Two","Three","Four"]
    var myIndex = Int()
    var Filter = [String]()
    var isSearching = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        TableView.delegate = self
        TableView.dataSource = self
        SearchBar.delegate = self
        SearchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if isSearching {
            return Filter.count
        }

        return Array.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 55
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = TableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.CellLabel.text = Array[indexPath.row]

        if isSearching {
            cell.CellLabel.text = Filter[indexPath.row]
        }else {
            cell.CellLabel.text = Array[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if SearchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
            isSearching = false
            view.endEditing(true)
            TableView.reloadData()
        }else {
            isSearching = true
            Filter = Array.filter({$0.contains(searchBar.text!)})
            TableView.reloadData()
        }}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        myIndex = indexPath.row

        switch myIndex {
        case 0:
            print("one")
        case 1:
            print("two")
        case 2:
            print("three")
        case 3:
            print("four")
        default:
            print("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably not related but never name variables with reserved words like `Array`. Use names starting with a lowercase letter to avoid terminology clashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put search `isSearching` logic inside `didSelectRowAt`

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  var index = 0

     if isSearching { 

         index = Array.index(of:Filter[indexPath.row])
     }
     else {

         index = Array.index(of:Array[indexPath.row])
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks ;) Have a nice Day

Answer (score 0):

Inside your tableView(:didSelectRowAt) method you have hardcoded indices from `0` to `3`. However, your tableView switches between `Array` and `Filter` collections. Moreover, the data in the `Filter` collection is subject to change depending on the text in the search field.

You could solve it like @Sh_Khan posted. But perhaps a better practice would be to have a filtered collection that is tied to the tableView and an unaltered collection containing all data.

That way, you don't have to check if `isSearching` is set in every method. In fact, you don't need it at all. You simply need to do the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Filter.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.CellLabel.text = Filter[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        view.endEditing(true)
        Filter = Array.compactMap({ $0 }) // Copies all elements from Array
    } else {
        Filter = Array.filter({ $0.contains(searchBar.text!) })
    }
    TableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(Filter[indexPath.row])
}
```

Comment: The delegate and data source methods should reference the local `tableView` parameter. Same for the search bar.

Comment: Yes, as @rmaddy pointed out, your implementation of `viewDidLoad` method should stay the same. I've only posted the methods that I would change.

Comment: Thank you! Have a nice Day ;)

Comment: I didn't say anything about `viewDidLoad`. I'm referring to the code in your answer (which is based on the code in the question).

Comment: @rmaddy it won't make a difference if it's the only tableView in the VC

Comment: @Sh_Khan No but by using the parameter you avoid any issues if the property changes or a second table view is added. As a general rule, use the local parameter over some class property.